# Cytoscape.js - Is there a way to draw edges on top of compound nodes?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to figure out a style/selector that could be applied globally to make edges draw on-top-of compound nodes using cytoscape.js.  I understand the value of having regular nodes always on-top-of edges but was wondering if there is a way to work around this with compound nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edges connecting to, from, or inside compound nodes are drawn on top of the associated compound nodes.  Unrelated edges are drawn behind, as usual.  You can control draw order with `z-index`, but those values are used relatively according to the hierarchy created by the previous rules.

It sounds like your graph has nodes placed too closely together.  Have you tried adjusting the [CoSE layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cose) options for your graph?

Comment: I'm having a different experience.  I am observing edges always drawing beneath compound nodes regardless of if they are to, from, or inside compound nodes.  Just to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious, I played around with the compound node example on the cytoscape.js site and had the same issue.  Any idea as to why they would not be displaying on top of compound nodes by default?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the issue and responding so quickly.  I grabbed the latest build (i.e. 2.2.13) to get the change but when I use this version of the file I get the following error:  "TypeError: cy is undefined" when I execute the following code:  var cy = $container.cytoscape("get");
var z = cy.zoom();  This was not occurring in the previous version.